# Python: weird results Scanning text files for a match

Tags: regex, python-2.7, operating-system

I'm trying to search through multiple files to find a match for every ingredient of a recipe. The search results were correct most of the times; however, there have been some situations were the results were and I can't pin point where the problem is. The code that I used and the text files that were scanned can be find below. Any help would be much appreciated and thanks.

The text files that were searched can be found at:
[All ingredient text file material](http://pastebin.com/rtH0nq43)

```
import os
import re

path_files = '/users/haida/desktop/Ingredients'
listing = os.listdir(path_files)

flag = 0

category = []
x = [ u' water ', u' fresh lemon juice ',
          u' uncooked quick-cooking bulgur ',
          u' cubed cooked chicken breast (about 1/2 pound) ',
          u' finely chopped fresh parsley ',
          u' (14-ounce) can quartered artichoke hearts, drained and coarsely chopped ',
          u' grape tomatoes, halved ',
          u" light Northern Italian salad dressing with basil and Romano (such as Ken's Steak House Lite) ",
          u' fresh lemon juice ', u'pork',u'cheese',u'apple', u'sugar', u'lime']

for i in x:
    for infile in listing:
        text = open(path_files + '/' + infile, 'r')
        for line in text.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            #if line.lower() in i[].lower():
            if (re.search(line.lower(), i.lower(),)):
                category.append(infile.rsplit('.txt', 1)[0])
                flag = 1
                break
    if flag != 1:
        category.append('others')

    flag = 0            
i = 0
print 'Right result:'
while i < len(x):
    print x[i] + '  ' + category[i] 
    i = i + 1

y = [u' bulgur wheat ',
          u' coarsely chopped onions ',
          u' ground lean (7% fat or less) beef or lamb ',
            u'ice'
          ,u' pepper ',
          u' ground cumin ',
          u' ground cinnamon ',
          u' About 1 teaspoon salt ','meat',
          u' chopped parsley ',
         'ice',
         u'meat',
          u' plain nonfat yogurt ']

for i in y:
    for infile in listing:
        text = open(path_files + '/' + infile, 'r')
        for line in text.readlines():
            line = line.strip()
            #if line.lower() in i[].lower():
            if (re.search(line.lower(), i.lower(),)):
                category.append(infile.rsplit('.txt', 1)[0])
                flag = 1
                break
    if flag != 1:
        category.append('others')

    flag = 0            
i = 0

print '\n \n'
print 'Correct Result: '
while i < len(y):
    print y[i] + '  ' + category[i] 
    i = i + 1
```

Note: You need to change the "path_files" value and separate the data in link among different text files to see the results.

Comment: You swapped the input text and regex pattern in `if (re.search(line.lower(), i.lower(),)):`, use `if (re.search(re.escape(i), line, flags=re.I))`

Comment: I have an impression you just need to use `if i.lower() in line.lower():` instead of `if (re.search(line.lower(), i.lower(),)):`.

Comment: It didn't work. I apologize 4 the delayed response